# Communication betwen sharepoint apps on different pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-apps, office365-apps

I'm developing two sharepoint hosted apps. App A shows a list of employees of the month(name, picture, etc) App B shows the detailed information for a certain employee of the month

What i'm trying to achieve is to redirect the user form the page that holds the app A to the page that contains app B when clicking an element from app A.

I've tried without success by using query string. I've read that you could communicate two apps with post message, but as i see it, that scenario won't apply to mine..

What could i do? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of App Sharepoint Hosted App or Provider Hosted App ? Redirect means click on <a> element and open a new window ? In this case you can use **QueryString** param OR for javascript you can use **localStorage**, if the app B is an IFrame inside App A you can use javascript **postMessage** [check this stackoverflow article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457391/how-do-you-use-window-postmessage-across-domains)

Comment: I'm using a Sharepoint Hosted App. Something i forgot to mention is that the communication described above is between two client web parts that belong to the same Sharepoint app project. Indeed it means to click on <a> element and open the client web part b on the same tab. In order to achieve this client web part A has a property named redirect Url which represents the url where client web part B is located.

Comment: Check this [stackoverflow article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581493/communication-between-two-iframe-children-using-postmessage) for communication between iframes

Comment: Maybe you could have them save a cookie value and the other to read the value upon loading.