# postMessage from iframe to parent with CORS error in Safari

Tags: reactjs, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I am developing a plugin (a React app) where I have two iframes (same domain) on a CORS site (different, i.e. client domain). Within this setup, I need to be able to communicate between:

1. One iframe to another (same domain)
2. iframe to client site (cross-domain)

For the **second (cross-domain)** case, I use the following code to deliver a message:

```
window.parent.postMessage(
  message,
  (new URL(document.referrer)).origin
)
```

which seems to work fine.

For the **first (same domain)** case, I use the following code:

```
const frames = window.parent.frames

for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {

  frames[i].postMessage(
    message,
    window.origin
  )
}
```

This also seems to work. However, in Safari (not in Chrome or Firefox) I get these error messages in the console:

```
Unable to post message to https://www.MY_DOMAIN.com. Recipient has origin https://www.SOME_OTHER_DOMAIN.com
```

The reason I'm blindly cycling through frames of the parent window is because I don't have a direct reference to my other iframe, and going deeper into the parent window to look for that iframe throws CORS errors... Like, for instance, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673075/2131598) points out.

Is there a better way to target the recipient of the message? Or at least to avoid the errors in Safari console?

Thanks!